# "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataOAuthAuthentication", referenced from:

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.5

i am new in ios developement.i have a project while run on ios 5.1 simulater it is working fine and not getting any error but in that same project while run on ios 6.0, ios 6.1 simulator i am getting following errors.Can anyone suggest me how can i rectify this problem?

**Errors:**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataOAuthAuthentication", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GDataOAuthViewControllerTouch.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataOAuthSignIn", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GDataOAuthViewControllerTouch.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

> The main problem was,I thought you  are using old GData sdk. You just
>   change the compiler to LLVM GCC 4.2 from Apple LLVM 4.2 and it
>   compiles app perfectly.

i have attached screenshot for your reference

Project->Target->Build Settings->Build options
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're linking against external libraries that haven't been compiled for your current architecture/SDK version. I see you're using VDOAds library, which was probably precompiled against the 5.1 SDK. You'll need to get a version that was precompiled for the latest iOS SDK.

Answer (score 0):

TargetSettings -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources  and make sure that these missing libraries are included there.

Answer (score 0):

So you have two problems, for the warnings, the libraries were added to your Build Phases but they were deleted from the project and they are still there.

For the error, the library that you are using is not added to Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries.

So in order to fix this warnings/errors, go to your project Targets -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries, and search for libGoogleAnalytics (I think this is the one for GA) and remove it (if not needed).

Also add the `VDOAds` library there in order to fix the error.

I also add a screenshot with the targets, it will be easier to find it if you don't know about  it. [image]